# How to read the JSON object when netwok is not available?

Tags: angularjs

I want to save json response object in local storage. If network is not available, I can read the data from local storage otherwise from the server. I didn’t see such condition anywhere.  
Thanks in advance.
**JSON**
[
   {
      "tid": "3388",
      "name": "Adagio Bar",
      "category_name": "Entertainment/Bars",
      "deck": "Sun Deck 16"
   },
   {
      "tid": "3439",
      "name": "Botticelli Dining Room",
      "category_name": "Food and Dining",
      "deck": "Fiesta Deck 6"
   },
   {
      "tid": "3399",
      "name": "Cafe Caribe",
      "category_name": "Food and Dining",
      "deck": "Lido Deck 15"
   },
   {
      "tid": "3377",
      "name": "Center Court",
      "category_name": "Pools, Sports & Spa",
      "deck": "Star Deck 19"
   }
 ]
**Controller**

```
'use strict';
var princess_at_sea = angular.module('princess_at_sea', [])
princess_at_sea.controller("locationList", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.locationList = null;
    $http.get("location.json")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.locationList  = data;        
            var indexedloc = [];
            $scope.locationListToFilter = function(){
                indexedloc = [];
                return $scope.locationList; 
            }
            $scope.filterLocation = function(Loc){
                var locationIsNew = indexedloc.indexOf(Loc.category_name) == -1;
                if(locationIsNew){
                    indexedloc.push(Loc.category_name);                 
                }
                return locationIsNew;
            }   
            $scope.returnFilterLoc = function(){return indexedloc};
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            $("div.content").html("Error");
        });
});
```

**HTML**
[image]

I have added a url too
http://jsfiddle.net/s1812ap8/

Comment: Have you tried just contacting the server, and then if that fails call your functionality (from the `.error()` handler) to load the object from local storage?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do what Mason mentioned above but do note about the 0 status code.

```
function error(response) {
    if (response.status === 0) {
       errorStatus = 'No connection. Verify application is running.';
    } else if (response.status == 401) {
       errorStatus = 'Unauthorized';
    } else if (response.status == 405) {
       errorStatus = 'HTTP verb not supported [405]';
    } else if (response.status == 500) {
       errorStatus = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else {
      errorStatus = response.data;
    }
   }
```